# Add encoding to a not encoded xml file

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, stream, zip

I'm using a WCF to unzip a file that I receive from an API (that I cant modifie).
The Zip file that I receive contains XML files that are not encoded. [image]

The problem is that I cant Deserialise these files later (I can't even load them to a XmlDocument).
I want to do one of these two:
1. Add the encoding when extracting the zip file,
2. Or add the encoding to the file before reading it later (just before deserializing it)
This is a pick from the code when extracting the zip file:

```
var subStream = entry.OpenReader();
Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);
subPath +="\\" + entryPath.Last();
using (var output = new FileStream(subPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
   {
       await entryStream.CopyToAsync(output);
   }
```

PS: Adding the encoding o the entry doesn't modifie the encoding when the file is saved.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by ' Add encoding'

Comment: Maybe you should try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961699/how-to-change-character-encoding-of-xmlreader

Comment: Can you use StreamWriter instead of FileStream and add Encoding.UTF8 or whatever enconding you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168325/changing-filestream-write-encoding-type

Comment: There is no "not encoded" for text-based files. String representation *always* needs an encoding. I guess it will be UTF-8 if nothing is stated explicitly. "I can't even load them to a XmlDocument" - what does that mean? Do you get an exception? If so, show the stacktrace please.

Comment: @Fildor this is the stacktrace:
http://imgur.com/a/JXWms

Comment: @Kenci I tried to use StreamWriter because it has and Encoding option but it writes strings not streams

Comment: @Fildor this is the text of the exception:
'.', valeur hexadécimale 0x00, est un caractère non valide. Ligne 2, position 1.

Comment: FileStream output = new FileStream(subPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            using (var output1 = new StreamReader(output, Encoding.UTF8)) { }

Comment: @MehdiSayeb Convert the XML string in the file with: byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); and use XDocument.Parse(myString); ?

Comment: @Kenci I can't get the XML string because I can't do anything with a not encoded stream.