# StreamReader C# does not read å, ä, ö

Tags: c#, special-characters

I have a `StreamReader` reading a file like below for reading a `.csv` file:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    line = sr.ReadLine()
}
```

The first line of the file is: `å ä ö Ü` (for testing purposes). However, when I try to read the file C# does not read the characters as it should:

[image]

Any idea why that is?

Comment: What's the encoding of the file?

Comment: It is a plain .csv file. Does such a file have an encoding? I did not consider that.

Comment: The string you got matches what you would get if you take "å ä ö Ü" encoded in UTF-8 (which is a likely candidate for how the CSV file is encoded), and then decode it as iso-8859-1

Comment: Yeah but can csv-files have an encoding? I did not know that.

Comment: All text must have an encoding. Otherwise it would be raw bytes. An encoding is what gives meaning to those bytes.

Comment: Okay, I have exported it from C# via `using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))` so you are probably right. How do I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151379/forcing-streamwriter-to-change-encoding

Comment: I see and you are right - thanks I did not know that. Can I resave it with notepad++ to a proper formate?

Comment: Windows? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-60d59c21-88b5-4006-831c-d536d42fd861

Comment: You could just read it real quick and resave it too. That's probably what I'd do :)

Comment: Yes, once I manged to resave the file problem was solved. A huge thanks for that. I did not think about that when I saved the file via C#... Learned something new today.

Comment: Wong encoding, it is UTF8.

Comment: Worth reading: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @KGB91 obviously all text files have encodings. *There's no such thing as plain text files*. Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove encoding or select the right one. I am using this  syntax without any problem

```
    string str = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\..."))
        str = r.ReadToEnd();
```

ouput

```
å ä ö Ü
```